# Why does merging pull request produces two commits?

Tags: git

Why does merging pull request produce two commits? Is this normal? Example these two commits are produced after merging pull request

https://github.com/square/retrofit/commit/39394b302809f80c1e089a194862094d16fc3eca

https://github.com/square/retrofit/commit/62a4a8308015f5efb51e20089fb8280d4454ed74

Comment: I'm not sure that you would always see two commits, but I believe your admin has GitHub configured to always make a merge commit.

Comment: any ideas how to change it so that it is just one commit?

Comment: Yes, you can try changing your GitHub settings.  If you don't have the rights to do that, talk to your organization about their policy.

Answer (score 1):

When you merge 2 branches, it always generates a merge commit.
In your example:

[Original Commit](https://github.com/square/retrofit/commit/39394b302809f80c1e089a194862094d16fc3eca): It is the change done in the story, it wasn't created by the merge action, but by the user when he was developing the feature. As you can see, this commit has only one parent.

[Merge Commit](https://github.com/square/retrofit/commit/62a4a8308015f5efb51e20089fb8280d4454ed74): It is the merge commit, it was created when merging the 2 branches. This commit has 2 parents, one is [Original Commit](https://github.com/square/retrofit/commit/39394b302809f80c1e089a194862094d16fc3eca) and the other is the [last master commit](https://github.com/square/retrofit/commit/39394b302809f80c1e089a194862094d16fc3eca) so, your commit will be here.

As it was mentioned in the other answer, the commits can be squashed into only one commit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only the Squash Merging option from the repo settings to enforce the Squash Merging. Which results in 1 single commit.

More about Merging: https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-request-merges/

Comment: I think i tried that and it didnt work. Let me try again. Is it best practise to leave it as it is (leave it producing two commits after mergin pull request)?

Comment: For me, yes :). Since it performs a --no-ff merge, keeping the information of the merged branch. But after all, it's preference. I've been using that configuration since the beginning and wouldn't mind the extra commit.